# Common ways Leibniz notation is abused

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

I've listed out a couple of instances where Leibniz's notation is abused, sometimes with nasty consequences. What are some other situations where Leibniz's notation is abused?

#### Chain Rule

Let $u = g(x)$ and $y = f(u)$, then:
$$(f(g(x)))' = \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \frac{du}{dx}$$

Even with differential forms, it is still a bit awkward. Let $u(x) = g(x)$ and $y(x) = f(u)$, then:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{ \frac{df}{du} du}{dx} = \frac{ \frac{df}{du} \frac{du}{dx} dx}{dx} = \frac{df}{du} \frac{du}{dx}$$

There's [plenty](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797636/the-differences-between-lagrange-and-leibnizs-derivative-notations) [of](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4127468/confusion-about-chain-rule-with-leibnizs-notation) [good](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797981/why-is-it-considered-less-precise-to-state-that-the-chain-rule-using-leibnizs-n) answers which discuss its problems and alternatives. But just to add on to it, here's a common example of its abuse:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt} \frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt} \frac{1}{ \frac{dx}{dt} } = \frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)}$$

This method is commonly shown in multivariable calculus courses when "deriving" curvature. Often called the *dummy variable* approach to "deriving" curvature. It's featured in [LibreTexts](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Supplemental_Modules_(Calculus)/Vector_Calculus/2%3A_Vector-Valued_Functions_and_Motion_in_Space/2.3%3A_Curvature_and_Normal_Vectors_of_a_Curve#Curvature_of_a_Curve) and [plenty](https://youtu.be/3RYeF5twUqk?t=125) of [educational](https://youtu.be/si6ka6HeUdY?t=130) [YouTube](https://youtu.be/kZF22Gyc9ZM?t=259) [videos](https://youtu.be/TnbRqkdVGso?t=742) "deriving" curvature. An actual derivation using Lagrange's notation is significantly more enlightening.

#### Multivariable Chain Rule for implicit functions

In Leibniz's notation, we can obtain the partial derivative for the implicit function $F(x, y, z) = 0$ as:

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = - \frac{\partial F / \partial x}{\partial F / \partial z}$$

Which can cause the contradiction:
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = - \frac{\partial F / \partial x}{\partial F / \partial z} \\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = - \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \frac{\partial z}{\partial F} \\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = - \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}
\end{aligned}

In Lagrange's notation, this is a non problem: $(z)'_x = - \frac{F'_x}{F'_z}$. This kind of contradiction has been discussed in, [other answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765044/challenge-demonstrate-a-contradiction-in-leibniz-differential-notation). The contradiction appears due to a misunderstanding/abuse of Leibniz notation which is very easy to make.

### Integration by substitution

Integration by substitution, or u-substitution, often includes a similar process. As an example:

$$\int (x+1)^2\ dx$$

Let $u=x+1$, then $\frac{du}{dx} = 1 \implies dx = \frac{du}{1}$

$$\int (x+1)^2\ dx = \int (u)^2\ \frac{du}{1}$$

Which is a helpful mnemonic, yet the same rule can be derived quite nicely from the  chain rule, as it's simply dividing out the $g'(x)$ produced by the chain rule. Again, this has been discussed in [other questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2727239/meaning-of-dx-dy-du-u-substitution).

### Separation of variables

This one is named after the abuse of notation. Unfortunately, it rather obscures the fact that it's simply integration by substitution:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = g(x) \cdot h(y)$$
$$dy = g(x) \cdot h(y) \cdot dx$$
$$\frac{1}{h(y)} dy = g(x) \ dx$$
$$\int \frac{1}{h(y)} dy = \int g(x) \ dx$$

This whole splitting step does almost [seem mystical](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356981/why-does-the-separation-of-variables-method-for-des-work), there are plenty of great [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525791/differential-equations-how-does-separation-of-variables-really-work) and alternatives to this method. It is unfortunate however that the name "Separation of variable" has stuck, which goes to show how prevalent the abuse of notation is.

### Green's theorem

$$\int_C Pdx + Qdy = \int_C (Pdx + Qdy) \frac{dt}{dt} = \int_C \left(P\frac{dx}{dt} + Q\frac{dy}{dt}\right) dt$$

While a bit unfair, since it is simply a differential form, the reasoning offered to students can only be characterised as an abuse of notation. Personally, I feel that hinting/suggesting differential forms is unnecessary and unhelpful in most multivariable calculus course.

Comment: separation of variables is no "mystical" at all, its completely correct and formal. From $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}y=f(y)$ you automatically have the equality of differential forms $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}y dy=f(y)dy$, where the result follows. Also it can be formalized using Robinson infinitesimals. Also integration by substitution its correct and formal, nothing strange is there

Comment: @Masacroso I'm regarding it as "mystical" to most calculus students who have never heard of differential forms or non-standard analysis. Of course, there's nothing strange here, I personally prefer explaining it as integration by substitution since it's makes most pedagogic sense. But yeah, a lot of these can be formalised with differential forms or non-standard analysis.